# Failed to register Bot with Microsoft bot framework

Tags: botframework

Just trying to register my bot with microsoft bot framework and it fails with
'object reference not set to an instance of an object'

here's bot endpoint: https://107.191.47.250:3979/

Probably somebody solved something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be resolved
Managed to create bot